# Python multiple inheritance: which __new__ to call?

Tags: python, new-operator, multiple-inheritance, class-hierarchy

I have a class `Parent`. I want to define a `__new__` for `Parent` so it does some magic upon instantiation (for why, see footnote). I also want children classes to inherit from this and other classes to get Parent's features. The `Parent`'s `__new__` would return an instance of a subclass of the child class's bases and the `Parent` class.

This is how the child class would be defined:

```
class Child(Parent, list):
    pass
```

But now I don't know what `__new__` to call in `Parent`'s `__new__`. If I call `object.__new__`, the above `Child` example complains that `list.__new__` should be called. But how would `Parent` know that? I made it work so it loops through all the `__bases__`, and call each `__new__` inside a `try:` block:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        # There is a special wrapper function for instantiating instances of children
        # classes that passes in a 'bases' argument, which is the __bases__ of the
        # Children class.
        bases = kwargs.get('bases')
        if bases:
            cls = type('name', bases + (cls,), kwargs.get('attr', {}))
            for base in cls.__mro__:
                if base not in (cls, MyMainType):
                    try:
                        obj = base.__new__(cls)
                        break
                    except TypeError:
                        pass
            return obj
        return object.__new__(cls)
```

But this just looks like a hack. Surely, there must be a better way of doing this?

Thanks.

- The reason I want to use `__new__` is so I can return an object of a subclass that has some dynamic attributes (the magic `__int__` attributes, etc) assigned to the class. I [could have done this in `__init__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129643/dynamically-assign-special-methods-to-objects-but-not-classes-in-python), but I would not be able to modify `self.__class__` in `__init__` if the new class has a different internal structure, which is the case here due to multiple inheritance.

Comment: I had an answer, but then I realized I totally misunderstood your question, so I deleted it and then revised it and undeleted it.  I think the new answer addresses your problem and will work.  I have done some minimal testing.

Comment: You are distinctly into the realm of metaclass programming, both tricky and wondrous.  The reason you are getting the error with __new__ is that `object` and builtin types like `list` and `dict`, as well as objects with `__slots__` all have different memory layouts.  

More insight in what you are trying to accomplish would help a great deal.  You might also want to look at using a class decorator or a function in the __metaclass__ slot.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need to modify self.__class__, you don't mention that. And if you need to do complicated magic like this in __new__, one solution that is often much easier is to not do it at all, but instead use a factory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will get you what you want:

```
return super(Parent, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
```

and you won't need the `bases` keyword argument.  Unless I'm getting you wrong and you're putting that in there on purpose.

Comment: I think this did it. I tried this before, unfortuantely, I had some other bug in my code that was preventing this from working.

The super function is one heck of a magic bullet.

Comment: @MTsoul, Indeed it is.  To be honest, I don't know why that worked exactly, I just figured it would.  :-)